# Is it possible for animals to become revenants?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-20th-anniversary

As far as I know, there are some cases where animals are ghouled for generations(Such as Nosferatu breeding pits) and I wanted to ask if it is possible for animals that have been ghouled for generations to eventually start giving birth to animals that are capable of producing their own vitae?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So while the other answer is correct for the most part, there *is* the possibility that some Revenant animals exist. It just might require you to be a Methuselah to pull off.

Beckett's Jyhad Diary has us visit Russia following Baba Yaga's death, and while there the narrator has a startling realization: the blood nourishes him as a human's might.

> The blood of the deer and rabbits that I summoned was sustaining me
> just like human blood. I don’t know why and I didn’t think to bring a rabbit back with me, but it tasted almost like ghoul blood. I didn’t see any other Kindred out there, though, and I was there more than a month. I must have killed two animals a night (even potent-blooded rabbits are still rabbits, they don’t hold much), and who in the world would waste that much of their blood making ghouls of all the rabbits in the woods at the foot of the Urals?
> [...]
> Slight digression here: We know ghouls can be bred into ghoul families, thanks to the sterling work of our friends the Fiends. And here we have a forest area with no Kindred, but a thriving ghoul animal population. My theory? Baba Yaga had ghoul animals, they escaped when she died, and bred their condition into the local species.

Granted this isn't an explicit confirmation, and it does raise the question of *how* this properly happened (as previous Revenant Families have required some form of sorcery to pull off, either Necromancy (for the Rosselini), Koldunic Sorcery (most), or so on.) That being said it definitely points towards it being somewhat possible, if incidentally so.

Answer (score 6):

### Most likely - no

To be a vampire one has to be human - the curse of Caine is passed only to humans and as far as I know, there are no animal-born cainites <sup>1</sup>

Revenants are some sort of hybrid - not fully human, not fully vampires. The WoD wiki says

> A Revenant is a kind of hybrid creature that is both like and unlike mortals, ghouls, and Kindred. Some would say a revenant is halfway between a mortal and a vampire; others would call it a **corruption of God's creatures with the curse of Caine**, mingling the two until they become inseparable.

If we'd take the emphasised part literary, it would be enough of a proof that this is impossible. <sup>2</sup>

Also, the OP has a bit of a misconception - it is not enough to keep "ghouling" families for generations to produce revenants - Tzimisce managed to do it only with extensive use of their disciplines and their success rate is rather limited to only a few families, now mostly extinct. If it was possible to do so on animals, they would probably try it by now.

On the other hand, I wouldn't be surprised if a Tzimisce would shape a human-revenant into looking something more animal-like.

<sup>1 Ok, there are EXTREMELY rare cases of Abominations - a short living Garou-Cainite hybrids, so in theory we could have a wolf (lupus) turned into some sort of a vampire...</sup>

<sup>2 But please remember, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence</sup>

Comment: In OWoD, there are some hints that it's possible revenants are descendants of dhampirs, children of thin-bloods, created and bred by Tzimisce. If you look at the rule systems governing both, you will notice that there are large overlaps. The dhampirs are basically revenants without family disciplines and family weakness.